# How to add object into an array javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an object to the expense array using the addExpense method.

```js
const account = {
    expenses: [],
    addExpense: function(description, amount){
        let addObject = {
            description : amount
        }
        this.expenses.push(addObject)
    }
}

account.addExpense('Shopping', 50)
console.log(account.expenses)
```

I get no errors but the result gives me an object using the parameter name and not the actual string value, 'Shopping'. The amount argument works fine.

```
[{"description": 50}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are setting the "description" property statically. You want a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), like so:

```
let addObject = {
   [description] : amount
}
```

#### Full Example:

```js
const account = {
    expenses: [],
    addExpense: function(description, amount){
        let addObject = {
            [description] : amount
        }
        this.expenses.push(addObject)
    }
}

account.addExpense('Shopping', 50)
console.log(account.expenses)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [computed property names](http://Computed_property_names) - an expression in brackets that evaluates to the key name (the `description` value in this case):

```
let addObject = {
    [description] : amount
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
const account = {
    expenses: [],
    addExpense: function(description, amount){
        let addObject = {
            [description] : amount
        }
        this.expenses.push(addObject)
    }
}

account.addExpense('Shopping', 50)
console.log(account.expenses)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let account = {
    expenses: [],
    addExpense: function(description, amount){
        let addObject = {};
        addObject[description] = amount
        this.expenses.push(addObject)
    }
}

account.addExpense('Shopping', 50)
console.log(account.expenses)
```

Comment: const =/= immutability. const merely says that the variable may not be *reassigned*, it has nothing to do with the value (in regards to object types).